# How to delete file from folder on server which is sent as an attachment in a mail using PHP

Tags: php

I want to delete pdf from folder which is sent as an attachment in a mail on a server.
I am trying this code :

```
if($mail->Send()) 
{
 unlink($file);
}
```

Its working on local but not on server.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: you need to provide proper path for delete a file

Comment: I am providing path too.

Comment: check for permission of that file.

Comment: how can i check that permission???

Answer (score 0):

If it is working on local, it means your file path is correct on your local project. I am sure that path of the same file is different and not correct that's same php built-in function `unlink()` does not working on server. You just need to provide correct path of the file, also you can use `file_exists()` which will check that file is available or not.

```
$file = '../your-directory/your_file.pdf';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

Also check the file permission because php function will be unable to delete any file if file has read only permission.

Comment: Thanx but how can i check the file permission??

Comment: @Neha if you are using Filezila then right click on the file and give full permission. It will show 777.